# Migrate products, sales and customer data to upgraded Magento dev site

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, database-update

I am in the process of upgrading my Magento website. I have started with a clean slate and done a fresh install of Magento 1.9.1 on a dev URL.

I imported my current LIVE database and performed the upgrade, and then began site development on the DEV site.

The LIVE site is still taking new orders, and having new products uploaded to it, as business must continue, of course.

When I am ready to launch the new site, how do I go about making sure the DEV site contains all of the LIVE sites products, customers and sales history, and anything else that is required along those lines.

There are a number of threads out there talking about dropping the DEV database and rerunning the upgrade on the LIVE database (once restored to the DEV database) and then launching - but all my site modifications stored in my DEV database would be lost if I did this!

I imagine there is a way to just copy the relevant data from the LIVE database to the DEV database to bring it up to date, and then I would be able to launch the new site. That being the case, can someone provide a list of the relevant tables that would need to be copied from the old LIVE to the new DEV database.

Sub-question... how do you get around the problem of any differences between the old (1.6.2) database and the new (1.9.1) database tables to be copied?

I hope someone can help.

Cheers,

Rob

Comment: You need to make list of the changes you are doing in the dev database and has to manually feed into new database that is the possible way.

Comment: There has to be an easier/better way than doing that. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to backup and restore you LIVE database to your DEV site often as thing will change. Documenting the procedure will help you when you finally do go live.

The easiest way to make sure you CMS and Static blocks are available is to create them in LIVE and restore that site to dev. You would then document the procedure to GO-LIVE by making sure all the necessary changes happen in Config, CMS and static blocks

Comment: Thanks. I already know this though. WhatI was looking for is a solution to moving product/sales/customer data from the LIVE db to the DEV db, as changes to the LIVE db will continue on during the development of the DEV site.

Comment: Why don't you just backup live and restore to dev?

Comment: As stated, the Dev site has been further developed, so dumping the database is not an option.

Comment: But the dev site would have to some day turn into the live site so why wouldn't you use your most recent data?

Comment: Just in case you missed them... here's the 2nd to 4th paragraphs of my question again :-) I imported my current LIVE database and performed the upgrade, and then began site development on the DEV site.

The LIVE site is still taking new orders, and having new products uploaded to it, as business must continue, of course.

When I am ready to launch the new site, how do I go about making sure the DEV site contains all of the LIVE sites products, customers and sales history, and anything else that is required along those lines.

Comment: You will need ultimately upgrade you LIVE database again!! That is why you want to make sure you have you upgrade process well documented so you can duplicate it. We normally upgrade a site 10-15 times before going live. Once you have your plan in place the upgrade will go smoothly.

Comment: The DEV database will become the LIVE database. My website is basically starting over, with a brand new magento installation. Once it has been fully developed and tested, the current LIVE website will be switched over to the DEV site, which will then become the new LIVE site. At that time, all new products, customers and orders etc which have been added to the currently LIVE site during the development period, will need to be moved over to the DEV site, so that it is bang up to date with those orders and customers etc. Then launched...

Comment: There is not a good work flow what what you are proposing. Good luck.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This is the only way I can minimise downtime on a very busy production site. What would you propose instead?

Comment: We use this process. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

Comment: Yes indeed - I am following this process too, for the most part. What it doesn't account for is developing a site where lots of elements are stored in the database, so the backup/upgrade/restore of the database will wipe out those developments, and they will all take too long to do again while the main website is down. What I have to do is develop the new site, and then update all of the data for products/customers/sales in the dev db to bring it up to date with the live db, then launch the new site - with the least amount of downtime possible.